# IE9 swfobject undefined

Tags: flash, internet-explorer

I m embedding a flash object on my page using swfobject's code below:

```
flashVars =
       appMode: appMode
       callback: "function(){app.broadcaster.webcam.emit.apply(app.broadcaster.webcam, arguments);}"
     params =
       quality: "high"
       bgcolor: "#ffffff"
       wmode: "transparent"
       allowscriptaccess: "always"
       allowfullscreen: "true"
       allowNetworking: "all"
       allowFullScreenInteractive: true
     attributes =
       id: id
       name: id
       align: "middle"
       classid: "clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"
     args = [
       "/bin-release-v2/fApp_1_9_beta4.swf"
       id
       "464"
       "348",
       "11.1.0"
       "/bin-release/playerProductInstall.swf"
       flashVars
       params
       attributes
       (e) =>
         app.log "embedded player!", "broadcaster"
         $el = $ e.ref
         webcam = WebcamBroadcaster.create $el
         @emit "embed", webcam
         deferred.resolve webcam
     ]
 swfobject.embedSWF args...
```

Everything works well, I can call methods on the object (including in IE9) but I get this error randomly:

```
document.getElementById("webcam").setReturnValue("<undefined/>")

SCRIPT 5007: Unable to get value of the property 'SetReturnValue': object is null or undefined
```

I m working on a socket.io based broadcasting website and this happens on the client side.

When the broadcaster disconnects, the flash object is removed from the client side and on connect it s embed again.

Could it be that there is a quick remove/embed on the flash and the IE9 browser is slower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving/Hiding DOM elements that contain the SWF object causes re-embedding, therefore its methods cannot be called "meanwhile".